# Xcode Cannot go back to TableViewController in navigation stack

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have controller1 -> TableViewController2 -> TableViewController3 in my storyboard. When I press a button in controller1, I want to jump to TableViewController3 and from there when I select a row, I want to go back to TableViewController2 and get some data and then go back to controller1.

In controller1 instantiate TableViewController3:

```
if segue.identifier == "MySegue" {
     let viewController:TableViewController3 = segue.destination as! TableViewController3
     viewController.addLocationToMap = true
}
```

In TableViewController3 instantiate TableViewController2 like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if addLocationToMap == true {
        let navc:UINavigationController = self.navigationController!
        let tvc:UITableViewController = TableViewController2()
        let rootView = navc.viewControllers[0]
        navc.setViewControllers([rootView, tvc], animated: true)
       return
    }
```

In TableViewController2 viewDidLoad, it fails in ViewDidLoad when I try to set a text field value because the textfield is nil. It cannot be because Textfield is already in the view. Looks like the TableViewController2 view never got loaded.

in TableViewController2

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
locationPurposeTextField.text = "sometext"
}
```

Fails when setting text value because locationPurposeTextField is nil.

How to fix this?

EDITS:
On pressing a button In controller1:

```
let navc:UINavigationController = self.navigationController!
        let alTvc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddLocationID") as! UITableViewController
        navc.pushViewController(alTvc, animated: false)
        let cListTvc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactListID") as! UITableViewController
        navc.pushViewController(cListTvc, animated: true)
```

The code takes me to TableViewController3 with storyboard ID: ContactListID as desired.

Next, in  TableViewController3

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
self.myDelegate?.userSelectedContact(contactIdentifier: self.contactId, contactFullName: fullName, contactSelected: true)
            let navc:UINavigationController = self.navigationController!
            let tvc:UITableViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddLocationID") as! UITableViewController
            let rootView = navc.viewControllers[0]
            navc.setViewControllers([rootView, tvc], animated: true)
}
```

Takes me to TableViewController2 with storyboard ID: AddLocationID
Based on the delegate sent TableViewController3, in ViewDidappear method of TableViewController2, I set some text in the view and call tableview.realoadData(). It does not load the view.

However if I select a button in  TableViewController2 and load TableViewController3 and then comeback to TableViewController2 upon execution of the very same method didSelectRow it reloads the view in TableViewController2

How to fix it, please let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your approach.

If you want to go from `controller1` to `TableViewController3` but have your navigation stack contain `controller1 -> TableViewController2 -> TableViewController3`, you will have to have the button in `controller1`  first push `TableViewController2` without animation, and then push `TableViewController3` with animation. (You won't be able to have your button trigger a segue.)

Second problem: You can't create a copy of your `TableViewController2` by just invoking it's initializer (`TableViewController2()`). When you do that it doesn't load its views from the storyboard. Instead, you should assign a storyboard identifier to it and use the `UIStoryboard` method `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` to create a new instance of it.

Comment: Ok, first suggestion: how to push controller without or with animation ? The second suggestion, I will include and try.

Comment: Take a look at the UINavigationController class reference in the Xcode help system. There is a section titled "Pushing and Popping Stack Items". That should answer your question. (Apple's documentation is pretty good. You should use it as your first source of information, and only post questions if you can't find answers there.)

Comment: The reason I am going forward and coming back is EX: controller1 does not have any location records to display then go create a record in tableviewcontroller3 ( passing through tableviewcontroller2 without loading view) and then go back to tableviewcontroller2 showing updated list of locations from which user can select a location and go back to controller1.

Comment: I will check the links

Comment: I made changes to the original posting by adding the code as suggested. Still getting errors,. Can you review and let me know your response?

Comment: "Still getting errors" is not helpful. You need to describe exactly what is going wrong. Are you talking about compile errors or run-time errors. What is the exact error, and what line number is it occurirng on?

Comment: I Posted errors in the original posting as Edits. The controllers worked fine, I had issue with delegates, but that was another error I fixed it. I accepted your answer